# What are the last two metals and what do they do?

Tags: mistborn, cosmere, wax-wayne-novels

I've recently finished the Mistborn trilogy by Brandon Sanderson and at the very end of the book:

> Sazed tells Spook: "P.S. There are still two metals that nobody knows about. You might want to poke about and see if you can figure out what they are. I think they'll interest you."

Is there a reliable answer to what they are and what they do? If there is another book to read that answers this please let me know.

Comment: Someone really needs to fix the front pages so that spoilerized text doesn't show.

Comment: I'm guessing you have already visited this [site](http://www.brandonsanderson.com/blog/719/The-Last-Two-Metalsandnbsp.andnbsp.andnbsp.-) . The link provided there does not work.

Comment: @Xantec:Check out the ["Alloy of Law" preview chapters on tor.com](http://www.tor.com/bios/authors/brandon-sanderson), where one of the characters can use one of the two remaining metals. It's a new trilogy set in the mistborn universe and releasing really soon.

Comment: Brandon has said he is going to write an Alloy of Law sequel, which may turn into a trilogy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The two unknown metals are [Cadmium](http://coppermind.17thshard.com/wiki/Cadmium) and [Bendalloy](http://coppermind.17thshard.com/wiki/Bendalloy), which allow the burner to slow down or speed up the flow of time in a bubble that surrounds them.

Answer (score 4):

Sanderson answered this question on his forum. While it is now offline, you can still find it in [Arcanum](https://wob.coppermind.net/events/243/#e5265).

> 3)  The last two metals are Chromium and Nicrosil.  We'll reveal what they do on the Allomancy poster.  Suffice it to say that in the next trilogy, the main protagonist would be a Nicrosil Misting.  And, to make a Robert Jordan-type comment, what those two metals do should become obvious to the serious student of Allomancy...  (It has to do with the nature of the metal groupings.)

Answer (score 2):

With the lead from @Darius and some additional digging I managed to find [this](http://mistborn.wikia.com/wiki/Allomantic_Table_of_Metals) table of Allomantic metals, which can apparently be bought through Brandon Sanderson's [website](http://www.brandonsanderson.com/) (although I can't get the store to load).

Comment: You should typically try to include the relevant text from hyperlinks into your answer, it makes them much much better.

Comment: Second link is now dead, I can't find a suitable replacement to what you might be referring.

Answer (score 0):

A list of all the metals I can find goes like this, there are 19,

Iron, steel, tin, pewter, zinc, brass, copper, bronze, aluminum, deralumin, gold, electrum, atium, and the eleventh metal: malatium. The new metals would be chromium, nicrosil, bednalloy, cadmium, and lerasium.